# How and why does Google and Apple approve the Amazon Prime video app with paid content not paid through their payment gateway

Tags: google-play, in-app-purchase, app-store, in-app-billing

Scenario 1) When you want to play a premium content (non-free) on amazon prime video app on android or iOS device, amazon used to 1) make you launch browser, 2) login to your account on amazon inside browser, 3) buy it, 4) make you come back to the prime video app and then you can watch the paid content in side the app.

Scenario 2) Recently amazon lets you purchase the same content inside the app, however it confirms the credit card of file with amazon.

This both scenario show that amazon is not sharing the money earned when customer buys paid amazon content with either google or apple. How is google and apple allowing this only to amazon app. Or does google and apple allow other apps to do the same?

I am planning to launch an app. The user will be required to buy subscription or pay per use. Will I be able to bypass google play store and apple App Store and save on 30% commission that they charge. I intend to use stripe for payments